# proof of product rule of derivatives using first principle?

Tags: calculus, differential

How can I prove the product rule of derivatives using the first principle?

$$\frac{d (f(x) g(x))}{d x}
   = \left( \frac{d f(x)}{d x} g(x) + \frac{d g(x)}{d x} f(x) \right)$$

Sorry if i used the wrong symbol for differential (I used \delta), as I was unable to find the straight "d" on the web.

Comment: Maybe you meant $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)g(x))= \frac{df}{dx}g+ \frac{dg}{dx}f$.  If so you just simply use the ‘d’

Comment: yes, I meant that only. but i wasn't able to find the latex symbol for 'd'

Comment: @MJW thanks, updated :))

Comment: `{\rm d}` gives $\rm d$ but using $d$ is also acceptable.

Comment: @mvw yes, the limit definition of a derivative.

Comment: If you know and apply the definition you are halfways through a proof.

Comment: You multiplied in the wrong order. $$ \begin{align} \text{right: }\quad & \frac d {dx} (f\times g)\qquad =\qquad \frac{df}{dx} \times g \quad + \quad f\times \frac{dg}{dx} \\  \\  \\ \text{wrong: }\quad & \frac d {dx} (f\times g)\qquad =\qquad \frac{df}{dx} \times g \quad + \quad \frac{dg}{dx} \times f \\ \\ {} \end{align} $$

Comment: If you want to use the "straight d" you can write $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm d x}. \qquad$

Comment: -1. This is in every calculus textbook... And easy to find online too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Proof_by_factoring_(Proof_from_first_principles)

Comment: Not in mine apparently.

Comment: @MichaelHardy does the order really matter? you have a Ph.D. in math, so I suppose it does matter.

Comment: @DakshMiglani : oh... I thought you were talking about a cross-product of vector-valued functions, since you wrote it as $f(x)\times g(x)$ rather than $f(x)g(x). \qquad$

Comment: yea totally in cross product the order does matter, but as I said I'm really new to latex so yea, didn't know that. I'll correct it tho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways of stating the first principle. 
The first one is $$\frac{{\rm d}f(x)}{{\rm d}x} =\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.$$
Then \begin{align}
\frac{{\rm d}\big(f(x)g(x)\big)}{{\rm d}x}
&=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)g(x+h) -f(x)g(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)g(x+h)\color{blue}{-f(x)g(x+h)+f(x)g(x+h)}-f(x)g(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0} \left( \frac{f(x+h)\color{blue}{-f(x)}}{h} \cdot g(x+h)
 +f(x) \cdot \frac{\color{blue}{g(x+h)} -g(x)}{h} \right)\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)\color{blue}{-f(x)}}{h} \cdot \lim_{h\to 0} g(x+h)
 +\lim_{h\to 0} f(x) \cdot \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\color{blue}{g(x+h)}-g(x)}{h}\\
&=\frac{{\rm d}f(x)}{{\rm d}x} \cdot g(x)
 +f(x) \cdot \frac{{\rm d}g(x)}{{\rm d}x}.\end{align}

The second way is $$f'(a) =\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$$
Then \begin{align}
(fg)'(a) &=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)g(x) -f(a)g(a)}{x-a}\\
&=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)g(x)\color{blue}{-f(a)g(x)+f(a)g(x)}-f(a)g(a)}{x-a}\\
&=\lim_{x\to a} \left( \frac{f(x)\color{blue}{-f(a)}}{x-a} \cdot g(x)
 +f(a) \cdot \frac{\color{blue}{g(x)}-g(a)}{x-a} \right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)\color{blue}{-f(a)}}{x-a} \cdot \lim_{x\to a} g(x)
 +\lim_{x\to a} f(a) \cdot \lim_{x\to a} \frac{\color{blue}{g(x)}-g(a)}{x-a}\\
&= f'(a) \cdot g(a) +f(a) \cdot g'(a).\end{align}

Comment: i think there needs to be a limit as well?

Comment: oh yeah, you edited. :)

Comment: Note that continuity in $x$ was used to go to the last line, which is a consequence of differentiability in $x$.